# How to use font awesome with css

Tags: css, font-awesome

How can I use font-awesome in css? I searched and see that I just need to download and copy font-awesome directory into my porject then display the icon by using content in css. But instead of displaying awesome icons, it displayed weird and undefinable characters. Does anyone know how to use/fix it properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "weird and undefinable"? Could you supply a screenshot?

Comment: What do you mean? Just include the _font-awsome.css_ in you project and then use it's classes - [reference](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/). Here is [a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/df2djb85/)(notice the _external resources_).

Comment: How do you use it in your project? show us your css code. Are you sure your page can find your css?

Comment: I found the cause. It is because of firefox doesn't allow cross domain font. Any one know how to fix it?

Comment: @valentincekristiana Please post a link to a fiddle (http://www.jsfiddle.com) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: here is the output: http://jsfiddle.net/df2djb85/1/.

Comment: @valentincekristiana your using it wrong. Just add the class like `<i class="fa fa-building"></i>` - see the [reference](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)(click on some icon and it will show you the markup).

Comment: It worked on google chrome but not firefox. I tried your way but same thing

Comment: @valentincekristiana here's your fiddle with the correct markup - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/df2djb85/2/)

Answer (score 0):

add this in the head of your html page: `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">`